# how to build openCV project to dll

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, opencv, dll

I have a `c++` project use `openCV` 
I built my `c++` project to a dll file to use in a `C#` project, but when I debug the `C#` project, it has an error: `Unable to load DLL,The specified module could not be found`.
please help me :D

Comment: you use some managed environment like CLI, right? C# dll and C++ dll's are different animals and you need to prepare some wrapper for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are loading the DLL using `P/Invoke`. Make sure `OpenCV's` dll's location is in your search path (the `Path` environment variable on 64 bit Windows 7) or that the dll and all of its dependencies are in the same directory as your managed executable. That directory is usually the `bin\Release` or `bin\Debug` directory.

Comment: is that means I should copy OpenCV's dll to bin\Debug directory of the C# project :D

Comment: In that case, please post some code, how are you loading the dll?

Comment: also, if OpenCV has any dependencies on other dlls, i.e. there are other dlls present in OpenCV's build directory, make sure to copy them over as well.